# Unable to grade student assignment in blackboard

Tags: university, software, grading

I created an assignment for students using blackboard. This assignment is something that is completed externally. When going into the grading center I am unable to assign grades unless the students have submitted something. How can I grade this without requiring them to submit anything? I've already tried setting the column as external the the category to no with worked for a different assignment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about the features of a particular piece of software, not about academia as described in the help center.

Comment: @JeffE Which site would you suggest for this question?

Comment: Maybe http://discussions.blackboard.com/ ?  Or your local IT people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the "Grade Center Assignments" page is only for assignments that students will submit through Blackboard.  For other graded items, go to "Full Grade Center" and click "Create Column".  You can then make a column into which you can type arbitrary grades.

Comment: I found a cleaner solution. If you click on the column and click "View Grade Details" you have the option to override grades.